# How to call the state again when added or deleted new information in ReactJS without manually refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been facing a problem. I already tried to solve it. But, I don't know how to get it to work. I know my problem is that I don't reupdate the Lists New state after I push or delete to the API? How can I fix this? So, I don't have to manually refresh the page?

**I have 2 components but in this post, I will only show the one I use for delete and read from API this post, which is called "Products". The PostForm component is a separate component that is imported into the Create/Delete component.**

I added this code in the setState for delete. I guess I need a function to reupdate the state but don't know-how. would appreciate help
**// productList: filter((item) => item.id !== productId),**

```
class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    productList: [],
    statusMsg: "",
  };

  // READ
  getDataFromProductsApi() {
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:44366/api/Products/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          productList: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ statusMsg: "Error retreiving data" });
        if (axios.isCancel(error)) return;
      });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromProductsApi();
  }

  // DELETE

  deleteProduct = (productId, productName) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      axios
        .delete(`https://localhost:44366/api/Products/${productId}`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({
            statusMsg: `Product name: ${productName} With the ID: ${productId} was removed!`,
            // productList: filter((item) => item.id !== productId),
          });
        });
    }
  };

  showProducts = () => {
    return (
      <table className="customers">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>

          {this.state.productList.map((product) => {
            return (
              <tr key={product.id}>
                <td>{product.id}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(product.id, product.name)}
                  >
                    X
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>
          <h1>Products</h1>
          <Postform /> {/*Adding the post Component to the view */}
          <div> {this.state.statusMsg}</div>
          {this.showProducts()} {/*running function to show data view */}
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve it. First: Call getDataFromProductsApi() function on Success of DeleteProduct. 

2nd: Find Product ID from the productList and splice it and update the productList setState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you mean?

https://jsfiddle.net/bq8h7ns9/

```js
class Products extends React.Component {
  state = {
    productList : [],
    statusMsg: "",
  };

  // READ
  getDataFromProductsApi() {
    this.setState({
      productList: [{ id : 0, name: 'blah1', price: 12.3, category : 'blah' }, { id : 1, name: 'blah2', price: 32.1, category : 'blah' }],
    });
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromProductsApi();
  }

  // DELETE

  deleteProduct = (productId, productName) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      this.setState({
        statusMsg: `Product name: ${productName} With the ID: ${productId} was removed!`,
        productList: this.state.productList.filter((item) => item.id !== productId),
      });
    }
  };

  showProducts = () => {
    return (
      <table className="customers">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>

          {this.state.productList.map((product) => {
            return (
              <tr key={product.id}>
                <td>{product.id}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.category}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.deleteProduct(product.id, product.name)}
                  >
                    X
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>
          <h1>Products</h1>
          <div> {this.state.statusMsg}</div>
          {this.showProducts()} {/*running function to show data view */}
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

You are already updating the component's state; that is what `setState` does. Your commented out line should be something like `this.state.productList.filter((item) => item.id !== productId)`, `filter` is not a global function.

If you mean you want your component to stay in sync with your api, then you will need to use something like websockets or long polling. Http is a stateless protocol.

Comment: i just want my view to Update the change. for instance i delete. it says delete sucsesfully but the item is still in the list . Once i update the item is gone.

Comment: The code I provided should demonstrate how to do that. I've replaced your axios calls with stubs but it works for me.

Comment: your solution worked fine. the productList: this.state.productList.filter((item) => item.id !== productId)
 how can i do the same to Adding item as i dont manage the IDS same way to update view

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. Most straight forward would be capturing this input in a form if you want the user to to enter the values manually, keeping the state of that form somewhere. When a user clicks i.e a button to add this data, create a new array of data out of what is currently in this component's state, and the new item you wish to add. Then call setState setting productList with that new data. If the shapes of data are different, you will need to add a transformation stage between clicking the button and making the new item so they are the same.

Comment: To keep things tidy, if you wanted that form to be it's own component, then you could pass it a function as a prop with adding/transformation logic defined in this component. But it is impossible to say if that is an appropriate solution unless I know what exactly what you are after.

Comment: i have a form in another component that can push to the api can i do the same since that component knows nothing about whats in the list

Comment: Yeah, pass that component a function you define in this component, which will contain the setState behaviour, as a prop, and have that component call the passed function when you submit it to update the state in this component.

Comment: can i do something like this?   updateState() {

    this.state
  }
and send this function as props and call it in other place

Comment: @ZombieTfk For adding the item. Push in the array and update the setState.

Comment: I mean how can i get the current state in a function call the api again?